# Can we set type from interface for a variable in typescript?

Tags: typescript

Below is my code

```
interface apiResult {
    Token: string;
    Result: any;
}

const result: apiResult = payload.Result;
```

What is this code mean?
Can we set type from interface to a variable?

Answer (score 0):

The interface is used to define what your TS class can receive so here the interface is defined as apiResult can accept a token which is a string and a Result of any type (dynamic).
If you need to strongly type a variable from the interface it should be done with a model

```
Result: ResultModel;
```

then define your ResultModel

example:

```
export class ResultModel {

//Fields 
id: number
documentId: number
someProperty?: string 

constructor (id: number, documentId: number){
   this.id = id
   this.documentId = documentId
}}
```

Here you build a model that states id and documentId must be populated where someProperty is nullable/optional